# MassTransit with AmazonMQ/ActiveMQ or SQS/SNS integration with AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, masstransit

Is there any way to use MassTransit with AmazonMQ or SNS+SQS and AWS Lambda?

I am new to serverless, AWS Lambda and AWS in general. I am implementing an event-driven architecture that is going to need some event bus for communication between microservices/lambda.

I have an app that needs to publish events, and I want to have many AWS Lambda that react to those events, do their work and go to sleep. I have had a look at AWS EventBridge but the latency (300ms to 600ms) is way too high for real time needs and it's not really designed for a large amount of subscribers. SNS + SQS is another option because I know MassTransit also supports it. Notice that RabbitMQ broker does not seem yet compatible with AWS Lambda as Chris mentioned in the comment below pointing to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html.

I've had good results with MassTransit in the past and I like the way it abstracts the transport layer away, but I can't find any opinion/sample on how to use it with AWS Lambda. Is it even possible? Any sample/link or reasons why it's not possible would be appreciated.

UPDATE: RabbitMQ cannot be used as broker for AmazonMQ if I want to use AWS Lambda. Question edited and it remains but applied to MassTransit + AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ broker) or SQS/SNS + AWS Lambda

Comment: They have an article on [using ActiveMQ with Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-mq-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/) and seem to indicate that it [only works with ActiveMQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html) at this point in time.

Comment: I see @ChrisPatterson, thanks for the link. I'll edit the question then, because using AmazonMQ with ActiveMQ is also an option. In fact I remember using MassTransit with AmazonMQ https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/activemq.html so the question remains.. Is it possible to use AmazonMQ/ActiveMQ with mass transit and AWS Lambda? or will I have to restrict MassTransit not to let it handle the topology is I want to trigger AWS lambda somehow?